# How to get Authorization in header with nginx?

Tags: php, apache, nginx, codeigniter-3

I am unable get Authorization in Header while i am using `nginx`.
in other hand when i use `Apache` then i am able to get that value using `apache_request_headers()`.
Actually i have upgraded our system apache to nginx.

Apache : - `apache_request_headers()`   => Working

Ex: `$headers = apache_request_headers();`

```
   $authorization = $headers['Authorization'];
```

nginx : - `apache_request_headers()`   => Not Working

Please suggest me to find Authorization in header with `nginx`.

Comment: the function is called that way for a reason :))

Comment: @ madalinivascu: - unable to get Authorization in your suggested 'Possible duplicate'

Comment: Yes Working Thanks @madalinivascu

Comment: glad to have helped